# Dynamic sheet name in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can reference a sheet name from another sheet

```
='Sheet1'!A1
```

How can I do thus with formula (not VBA or Python, sadly) to find out the name of the sheet dynamically (ie without knowing the name sheet)? Just to be clear I'm after the sheet names/ tab names at the bottom of the window, not the worksheet name

I've got number of spread sheets with a number of sheets (all named differently) and I was looking for a formula that will work with all. One size fits all , if you will.

Comment: u can try `=cell("filename")` to retrieve it

Comment: That just gives the filename & filepath, I'm after the tab names

Comment: yup. but it also gives the tab name. i know it sounds wierd but it does. so you can extract the name by using some function like RIGHT()

Comment: The thing with that is you'll still need to have a reference to the sheet to get the sheet name from that cell. I think the OP is asking if it's possible to get a list of all the sheets in the workbook without using references to the sheets themselves, which I think is going to be impossible without VBA. I'll keep an eye on this thread though, I'll happily be proven wrong if it means I learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In the *Name Manager* create a Name using this formula:

```
=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")
```

[image]

Then in your worksheet, use *INDEX function* to retrieve sheet names like this:

```
=INDEX(SheetList,1)
```

To List all sheets then select the target range and enter *SheetList* as array formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
{=SheetList}
```

[image]